# Syntax error with mysql when trying to fetch data from database using options in drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

When I select an option to retrieve certain data from my db, I get this error message:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.`

Why is that? There's nothing at line 1?
Also, could you teach me how to search in the retrieved data?

Example. if I choose option 1 "Antal narvaro" and press the Ok-button, the following sql-query will execute: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE fran = 'besok';`

Once I've retrieved this data, I want to further search in it for certain information like name, age and so on. Otherwise I'm grateful that I could just execute the following SQL-queries by choosing option in drop down list then press OK-button.

I'm very new to **PHP** and HTML, thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>AiFind</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/278x186q90/844/k32d.png" 
                 height="70" width="100" alt="Aifind-logo copy"></h1>
    </body>

</html>


<?php

include "connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    switch($_POST['filter']) {

        Default: 
            $sql .= " ";
            break;
        case 1:
            $sql .= " * from mytable WHERE fran = 'Besök'; ";
            break;
        case 2:
            $sql .= " * from mytable WHERE fran = 'Bok'; ";
            break;
        case 3:
            $sql .= " Postort, COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE AAA_diam != ";
            $sql .= " 'missing' GROUP BY Postort; ";
            break;
        case 4:
            $sql .= " *, COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE AAA_diam = 'missing'";
            $sql .= " GROUP BY Postort";
            break;
        case 5:
            $sql .= " COUNT(*) AS Antal_over_30 FROM mytable WHERE ";
            $sql .= " AAA_diam > 30 AND AAA_diam != 'missing' AND ";
            $sql .= " AAA_diam != 'n.a' AND AAA_diam != 'Missing'";
            break;
        case 6:
            $sql .= " COUNT(*) AS Antal_over_30 FROM mytable WHERE ";
            $sql .= " AAA_diam > 50 AND AAA_diam != 'missing' AND ";
            $sql .= " AAA_diam != 'n.a' AND AAA_diam != 'Missing'";
            break;
        case 7:
            $sql .=  "";
            break;

    }

}


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


?>


<!--Sökrutan där sökord matas in -->
<form name="Select_filter" method="POST" action="VGR_data_display.php">

    <select id="dropdown" name="filter">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Antal narvaro</option>
        <option value="2">Antal franvaro</option>
        <option value="3">Antal narvaro: destination</option>
        <option value="4">Antal franvaro: destination</option>
        <option value="5">Antal A_diam > 3cm</option>
        <option value="6">Antal A_diam > 5cm</option>
        <option value="7">Antal franvaro: procent</option>

    </select>

    <!--search bar for search term input -->
    <input id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
    <input id="submit" type ="submit" name ="search" value ="Ok">

</form>

<table style="margin:auto;" id="table" border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>F_ar</th>
<th>Postnr</th>
<th>Postort</th>
<th>Vardgivare</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Orsak</th>
<th>Planerat_datum</th>
<th>fran</th>
<th>AAA_diam</th>
</tr>


<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['F_ar']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Postnr']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Postort']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Vardgivare']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Team']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Orsak']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Planerat_datum']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['fran']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['AAA_diam']; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo `$sql` to see what the output is?

Comment: It means line 1 of your query. Also, you're using a deprecated API. Get modern.

Comment: ^^ That means `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed soon. You should be using `mysqli`

Comment: I've tried to echo $sql, still same error message.

Comment: I think it's about wrong symbols like `ö` in the sql-query. Сollations must be compatible.

Comment: I have checked, that's not the problem.

Comment: No one got a solution for this problem? Hmm, such a troublesome problem.